# Schengen visa port of entry

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

My wife and I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by France. I have traveled to France for business but my family didn't accompany me at the time.

Now we are planning to go to Italy or Greece and my family won't go to France. Will we have an issue here as they never traveled to France (and won't during this travel) where France was the the country issuing the visa for them in the first place?

Comment: Where are you from? And why didn't your family travel to France if they applied there for a visa?

Comment: I am from Jordan .Logistical issue caused a change in plan hence they couldnt join me to France.